# Javascript Validating in a loop

Tags: javascript

I have two radio buttons on the top (YES/NO) If yes the javascript function showhideform shows another text box(certificate). This form is in a loop as you see with all my outputs.If yes is chosen and loop is 1 everything works fine onsubmit. If Yes and I submit when loop is 2 it only validates certificate textbox 2 and forgets about  certificate textbox 1. I need it to validate both if yes is chosen twice.

Radio Buttons:

```
<input
 type="radio"
 value="No"
 name="abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>"
 id="noabc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>"
 onchange="showhideForm_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>(this.value);"/>
<label for="noabc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>">No</label>

<input 
 type="radio"
 value="Yes"
 name="abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>"
 id="abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>"
 required="yes"
 onchange="showhideForm_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>(this.value);"/>
<label for="abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>">Yes</label>
```

Show / Hide Radio Buttons:

```
function showhideForm_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>(abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>) {
    if (abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput> == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div1_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div2_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>").style.display = 'none';
    } 
   else if (abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput> == "No") {
        document.getElementById("div2_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div1_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Validating through loop:

```
 function doSubmit(n) {
        var QnoText = ['abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>'];  // add IDs here for questions with optional text input
           var ids = '';
           flag = true;
           for (i=0; i<QnoText.length; i++) {
               CkStatus = document.getElementById(QnoText[i]).checked;
               ids = QnoText[i]+'Certificate_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>' + n;
               if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids).value == '') {
               alert('Please enter certificate number ' + n + '.');
               document.getElementById(ids).focus();
               flag = false;

          }
        }
    return flag;
    }
```

Certificate textbox:

```
<input
 type="text"
 name="abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>Certificate_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>"
 validateat="onSubmit"
 validate="maxlength"
 id="abc_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>Certificate_<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>"
 size="54"
 maxlength="120"
 value="">
```

submit button:
    //return doSubmit(1);

Comment: The node ids you seem to be looking for include tags; is that correct?

Comment: @David, Can you actually give some context to your Question? What are you trying with this code? What is the story behind using certificates?

Comment: it looks like n is an argument and that is not changing, so loop runs twice it will check id's for all the n's it won;t go to the 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of working on it I have finally figured it out!! I just wanted to say thanks to everyone that has helped and this is the code for anyone who was interested!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSubmit() { 
    var count =<cfoutput>#BAdd#</cfoutput>;
    flag = true; 
    for (i=1; i<=count; i++){
    var ids = 'abc_'+i +'Certificate_'+i;
    var Radio = 'abc_'+i
        CkStatus = document.getElementById(Radio).checked; 
            if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids).value == '') {
            alert('Please enter certificate number ' +i);
            document.getElementById(ids).focus();
            flag = false;

        }
    }
  return flag;
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the n is just a numbering/index to the id of the input textbox it is validating.

Looking at your code, CKStatus seems to me is a checkbox. If it is checked, it will validate the certificate input text box according to the parameter n.

Comment: Why does you answer seem like a comment :P

Comment: Edit your question and add more details please